# bootstrap navbar scroll issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I need help with bootstrap. I am beginner with Bootstrap. I decided to use a template for my blog. I could customize many things but I get stuck with the header-nav. When I scroll the page the sticky nav bar is shifted and the menu cannot appear normally. If someone has got any suggestion ?

Link to the template I am using

[Template](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/clean-blog)

Link to my blog:

[Permacultivons](https://hardcore-wiles-5f54d6.netlify.app/index.html)

I have to mention that I have 2 .css (1 minified).

The initial CSS code:

```
#mainNav {


position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand img {
    height: 6rem;
    padding: 10px;
    
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #343a40;
}

#mainNav .navbar-toggler {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #343a40;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand:focus, #mainNav .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a:focus, #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav {
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed {
    /* when the user scrolls down, we hide the header right above the viewport */
    position: fixed;
    top: -67px;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-brand {
    color: #212529;
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-brand:focus, #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #0085A1;
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a {
    color: #212529;
  }
  #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a:focus, #mainNav.is-fixed .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a:hover {
    color: #0085A1;
  }
  #mainNav.is-visible {
    /* if the user changes the scrolling direction, we show the header */
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
}

header.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-color: #868e96;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

header.masthead .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #212529;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

header.masthead .page-heading,
header.masthead .post-heading,
header.masthead .site-heading {
  padding: 200px 0 150px;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header.masthead .page-heading,
  header.masthead .post-heading,
  header.masthead .site-heading {
    padding: 200px 0;
  }
}

header.masthead .page-heading,
header.masthead .site-heading {
  text-align: center;
}

header.masthead .page-heading h1,
header.masthead .site-heading h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fix

```
#mainNav.is-fixed {
/* when the user scrolls down, we hide the header right above the viewport */
position: fixed;
top: -137px;
transition: transform 0.2s;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
```

}

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please provide some explanation as well !!

Comment: @Iftikhar  thank you for your help :) It works better. When i scroll down it disappears and when i scroll up it appears. May be I need to had a sticky one, what do you think ?